# MUI Autocomplete single array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply the principle of `Add xyx` in MUI Autocomplete in Reactjs, using single dimension i.e `[1,2,3,4,5]`, i.e. without objects, So far I have got the examples and references with objects only. Is there any way possible to achieve so, for reference I am trying to achieve [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#creatable) using only single array, and I want the `Add <YOUR_SEARCH_TERM>` option, I have so far got only the input search term, I want to append `Add` as a prefix but if I add that `Add`, it also reflects in the input box as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way you can achieve this. Please see the [Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-proskuriakova-r4z3m3) I created. I modified the [Material UI example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#creatable) you had linked.

In this example, the options are numbers in an array, instead of objects i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

There are three steps:

1. To include the suggestion to `Add` the user's input in the filtered options, we push the user's input with the `Add` prefix.

```js
filterOptions={(options, params) => {
  const filtered = filter(options, params);

  const { inputValue } = params;
  // Suggest the creation of a new value
  const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option);
  if (inputValue !== "" && !isExisting) {
    filtered.push(`Add ${inputValue}`);
  }

  return filtered;
}}
```

2. As you rightly pointed out, if you select this, the `Add` prefix will also appear in the input box. For example, if we select `Add 6`, the input box will show `Add 6`. We only want to show `6`.

   We can achieve this by adding a [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in the `getOptionLabel`
   function. This controls how the option is rendered. Here we are
   replacing `Add`  from the option we selected with an empty string.
   This removes the `Add` prefix and the space between the prefix and
   the input. For example, instead of `Add 6` being displayed, only `6`
   will be displayed.

```js
getOptionLabel={(option) => {
  // Value selected with enter, right from the input
  if (typeof option === "string") {
    const updatedOption = option.replace("Add ", "");
    return updatedOption;
  }
  // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
  if (option.inputValue) {
    return option.inputValue;
  }
  // Regular option
  return option.toString();
}}
```

3. We also don't want to save the value with the `Add` prefix when we `setValue` in our `onChange` function. Similar to Step 2, we have to add a `replace` in the `onChange` function to remove the `Add` prefix.

```js
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
  if (typeof newValue === "string") {
    const updatedValue = newValue.replace("Add ", "");
    setValue(updatedValue);
  } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
    // Create a new value from the user input
    setValue(newValue.inputValue);
  } else {
    setValue(newValue);
  }
}}
```

Putting it altogether:

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import "./styles.css";

const numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const filter = createFilterOptions();

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          if (typeof newValue === "string") {
            const updatedValue = newValue.replace("Add ", "");
            setValue(updatedValue);
          } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
            // Create a new value from the user input
            setValue(newValue.inputValue);
          } else {
            setValue(newValue);
          }
        }}
        filterOptions={(options, params) => {
          const filtered = filter(options, params);

          const { inputValue } = params;
          // Suggest the creation of a new value
          const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option);
          if (inputValue !== "" && !isExisting) {
            filtered.push(`Add ${inputValue}`);
          }

          return filtered;
        }}
        selectOnFocus
        clearOnBlur
        handleHomeEndKeys
        id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
        options={numbers}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => {
          // Value selected with enter, right from the input
          if (typeof option === "string") {
            const updatedOption = option.replace("Add ", "");
            return updatedOption;
          }
          // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
          if (option.inputValue) {
            return option.inputValue;
          }
          // Regular option
          return option.toString();
        }}
        renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option}</li>}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        freeSolo
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Array of numbers demo" />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```